# Combine iOS and Web analytics

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I am using Google analytics for my Web application and iOS application.
iOS application is practically an equivalent of its Web counterpart (they have same views, same functionalities).
I would like to have a combined report analyzing usage of both iOS and Web app *together*.
That means sum of all pageviews, tracking user's actions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quantcast Measure is designed for cross platform (web and mobile app) audience measurement. It has both a web SDK and a [mobile app SDK](https://info.quantcast.com/MeasureApps_mk.html) that allows to to combine your web and app audiences into one comprehensive report. [Quantcast's profile of GoodReads](https://www.quantcast.com/p-0dUe_kJAjvkoY) is a good example of what it's cross platform reporting is about.

(Full Disclosure: I work at Quantcast)

Answer (score 0):

Forget about your mobile application, just create a responsive design version of your web app.

You will still be able to determine what traffic comes from Mobile devices.